# How to expose machine via IP to outside network for server access?

Tags: networking, internet, port-forwarding, webserver

I have an older PC that I stripped down and loaded Ubuntu on as I want it to function as a test serve for me to run concepts on for some personal projects. When up and running I can do a `hostname -I` and get back `192.168.1.1`, but I believe this is a private IP address, referencing the machine on the LAN below the router level. Visiting sites, such as https://whatismyipaddress.com/ will yield `70.108.1.98`, and I would like to be able to open a browser and be able to navigate to say `https://70.108.1.98:4321`, where an application is running on that port, expecting traffic.

Currently, if I want to connect to the server running on another device, I can open a browser on one machine and visit the private IP of that machine at `4321` and connect without issue. This makes sense, as its a LAN and the subnet masking allows these IPs to find each other under the router.

My initial estimation is that I'd need to do some of the following:

1. Configure the router to allow traffic on the firewall at `4321`
2. Forward all traffic at `4321` to the specific `192.168.xxx.xxx` IP indicating the specific machine on the network
3. Configure the web server running on the machine to accept traffic at `4321`

I guess the only other question I have is if that IP provided by the given link, representing my public IP, represents the router itself or the machine that I went to visit the site on? In other words, if I went to that site on my phone connected to my WiFi, would the IP be the same, thus indicating all devices on my router have that public IP and the router, well routes, traffic to the private IP of the device?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so, you want to do port forwarding, with "hairpinning" (for the bit about accessing WAN IP from within the LAN) - most routers do port forwarding easily, not many consumer routers do hairpinning at least not easily

Comment: @JaromandaX I am a SWE, so some of the network terminology/architecture is beyond my expertise. I have a machine hosting a web server, and I would like to access it from anywhere, the question is how? What do I need to configure so that a computer, at say my friend's house, could use my public IP to visit the app running on a machine in my house (if exposed)?

Comment: look up port forwarding for your router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like there are two scenarios/questions that you are looking for an answer to (correct me if I'm wrong).

1. You would like to host a service on port 4321 and have it accessible from the public Internet (using your public IP) and your private network (using your public IP or your private IP). To do this, you need to port forward your router to have port 4321 on your router be redirected to port 4321 on your Ubuntu machine. First step is to determine your Ubuntu servers private IP address (can be found with the command `ip a`). Second step is to follow the relevant steps to port forward your router (this site is a collection of port forwarding guides for a large number of router models: https://portforward.com/router.htm). Once these steps have been completed and a service is running on your Ubuntu server port 4321, you will be able to access it using your public IP.
2. With the second question you seem to be on the right track. Your router will have created a Network Address Translation (NAT) network to handle the routing between the public and your private network. This is the difference between the IP address that your Ubuntu server says it is, and the IP address that the external sites say they are. Any device that is connected to the Internet through your router will be part of the private NAT network, and the public IP address will be the same for all those devices (so a device on your Wi-Fi will have the same public IP address as your Ubuntu server).

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the only other question I have is if that IP provided by the given link, representing my public IP, represents the router itself or the machine that I went to visit the site on? In other words, if I went to that site on my phone connected to my WiFi, would the IP be the same, thus indicating all devices on my router have that public IP and the router, well routes, traffic to the private IP of the device?

In such situations, the IP address usually belongs to the router itself. It is never actually *shared* between machines having private addresses; they are mostly unaware of it.

- Your devices initiate connections from their private IP address as the source, which the router transparently translates to its own public address via SNAT.

  Upon receiving packets back from the internet, the router first checks whether they match a known translation; if they do, their destination is translated back to the host's private IP address; if they don't, then the router itself accepts the packets as the destination host.

  This isn't just "routing," exactly – the translation (NAT) is an additional feature *on top of* routing. All ISP routers further along the path only forward packets without performing any additional translation. (So could your router, if your network had public IP addresses for all hosts, as is the case in most IPv6-capable networks.)
- Similarly, when you set up a "forward all traffic to <IP>" rule on the router, you're actually setting up a NAT (translation) rule. The machine never knows that it was accessed using the public IP address; all packets it receives only have the private address.